# Problemas al ordenar archivo csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una pequeña función realizada en python en su versión 3.8, deseo ordenar una lista de un archivo csv pero al momento de realizar el ordenamiento solo me arroja como resultado una fila, adjunto la imagen del contenido y posteriormente el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def Leer():
    f = open('scoresNY1.csv','r',encoding='utf8')
    header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    info = []
    i=0
    for line in f:
        datos = line.strip()
    info.append(datos)

    lista =[info]
    lista.sort()
    print (lista)
```

Este es el resultado

**[['01M448,University,Manhattan']]**

Alguien me podría ayudar con esto ya que soy nuevo en el lenguaje y es una tarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está sucediendo porque tienes `info.append(datos)` fuera de tu bucle for, por lo que solamente te incluye el último valor de `datos` (la última línea). Si lo metes dentro del bucle te añadirá todos a la lista.

Por otro lado, deberías llamar a tu función leer() en vez de Leer(), las mayúsculas se reservan para las clases.

Tampoco sé muy bien para que es el  `lista =[info]` ya que estás metiendo tu lista (de un solo elemento) dentro de otra lista para luego ordenarla, y al tener un solo elemento no va a ordenar nada.

Igual querías hacer después del bucle `for`:

```
info.sort()
print(info)
```